# JDBC in Tomcat - Why getting "Connection Refused Bad File Descriptor"?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a SpringBoot app that's using Connection Pooling. Thanks to Tim for that suggestion.

When I run this app inside Tomcat normally (that is, not in debug mode), it all works great. Deploys, etc.

But, if I try to run the app in debug mode (catalina.sh jpda start), it fails with:

```
23-Jul-2023 10:18:11.906 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.filemaker.jdbc.FMSQLException: [FileMaker][FileMaker JDBC] Connection refused: Bad file descriptor
at com.filemaker.jdbc1.CommonJ1Connection.openConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.filemaker.jdbc.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:346)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:227)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:775)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:703)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:502)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.filemaker.jdbc.FMSQLException: [FileMaker][FileMaker JDBC] Connection refused: Bad file descriptor
```

Then, if I go back into the web app and change the JDBC from FileMaker to MySQL or to SQL Server, debug works fine. No errors.

Can I assume from these tests that there's something goofy going on with this Claris, Type III, JDBC driver?

I'm on the latest version of SpringBoot 2.x, Java 17.

Comment: Are the tomcat and the working java application running on the same machine? If not, then is it a connectivity issue from the host to the DB server? Or perhaps it is a configuration issue. How are you getting the connection string, username, etc. into the java code? Via config, ENV or hard coded? Is there an issue with something there?

Comment: *Debugging the JDBC code, the values are all correct (jdbc connection string, user, and password)* What's the value of the first of these?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Was just a subtle firewall configuration item.